# How to type returned tuple with template types

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function like this (can't give the implementation).

```py
T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")

async def foo(mark: T, *coroutines: Awaitable[U]) -> Tuple[T, *Tuple[U, ...]]:
   pass
```

It should return a tuple like `(mark, coro1_result, coro2_result, ...)`.

Is it possible to type it ina way that it's return type will hold exact return types of the co-routines? I tried playing with `TypeVarTuple`, but still didn't come to anything

Comment: No, there is no way to express that with tuples, the tuple type is either heterogenous and fully specified or homogenous with unknown size. You should jsut define a return type, with a dataclass, and return that type.